# x-Values Data not showing in Highcharts, Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, highcharts

I am plotting a graph using CSV files which contain two columns; one for the X-axis and another for the Y-axis.

I am able to get the Y-axis data in the chart but the data from the X-axis is not showing.

I can fetch the X-axis data in the console but it's not being displayed in Highcharts.

**The X-axis and Y-axis data are shown below:**

[image]

I am able to scatter the Y axis data on the graph but the X-axis data is not being displayed. Instead it only displays the count numbers from 0 to 16 as you can see below.

[image]

I am not able to figure out what I am missing in my code.

**Code:**

```js
$.get('peaks-data.csv', function(data) {
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  var xterms=[];

  $.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent) {
    if (lineNo >= 0) {
      xterms[lineNo - 0] = lineContent.split(',')[0];
    }
  });

  var yterms=[];

  $.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent) {
    if (lineNo >= 0) {
      yterms[lineNo - 0] = parseFloat(lineContent.substring(lineContent.lastIndexOf(",") + 1));
    }
  });

  xvalues = [] ;
  xValues = xterms;
  yValues = yterms;
  zip = (xs, ys) => xs.reduce((acc, x, i) => (acc.push([x, ys[i]]), acc), []);

  Highcharts.chart('ppg', {
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Data',
      data: zip(xValues, yValues)
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: can you check the zip() returns the proper values array ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to numbers also `x` values:

```
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent) {
    if (lineNo >= 0) {
        xterms[lineNo - 0] = parseFloat(lineContent.split(',')[0]);
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6jgx1av2/